# Video Live Streaming

Tags: windows-phone-7, smooth-streaming

trying to launch a video streaming request with smooth Streaming i tried this example with their url and also my uri " but it didn't work , i tried it on vlc also it worked with an iphone application .. ! this is a part of my xaml code :

```
<Core:SMFPlayer>
                <Core:SMFPlayer.Playlist>
                    <Media:PlaylistItem   DeliveryMethod="AdaptiveStreaming" MediaSource="http://streaming.toutech.net:1936/live/jawharafm.sdp/playlist.m3u8"/>
                </Core:SMFPlayer.Playlist>
            </Core:SMFPlayer>
```

Answer (score 1):

SMFPlayer does not support [HLS streaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming). For WindowsPhone you may want to use [SmoothStreaming](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/smooth-streaming)

Also, there was a project on codeplex that could play HLS streaming on a WindowsPhone, however it is not online anymore. I only found the tweet that referenced this project: https://twitter.com/JustinAngel/status/179253691549888514

---

**Update**

The HLS streaming for WindowsPhone is back online: http://phonesm.codeplex.com/